# Memory allocation for constant char array

Tags: c

If I write char * p = "Welcome".
I can see the address for p. But what's the address for the string i.e at which address Welcome stored?

If I write again char *s = "Welcome". p and s will point to same address?

Answer (score 2):

In a debugger, if you inspect `p`, you will see the address of the string.

`&p` is the address of `p` itself.

And no, `p` and `s` are not guaranteed to point to the same address, but they might.

Comment: Indeed. Some compilers recycle string constants, so the addresses may be the same.

Comment: Thanks in .map file I see the address      .conststring        0x080717d8   Section  main.o(.conststring)

Comment: Thanks the string address in same and not re-created so address pointed by p ans s are same.

Answer (score 0):

"Welcome" is string constant and it is stored in read only data section of memory but pointer p is created in stack which points to this string literal

Comment: The question does not imply anyhow that p is a local variable. It can be in the data section as well (writable) and not on the stack.

Comment: Thanks..How to print the address of this const string? *p gives the the string value and &p gives p address.Sorry to bother you guys.  Printing *p with %s gives string and %x giving the address. Hope what comes on print with %x is the address of constant string.

Answer (score 0):

String constant "Welcome" often are putted in "read-only-data" section of memory. 
Here are good explanations about: [String litereals where do they go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589949/c-string-literals-where-do-they-go) and [data segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment)

you can find the address of string constant "Welcome" by

```
 printf("%p",p);
```

> If I write again char *s = "Welcome". p and s will point to same
>   address?

Maybe same string constant are putted in the same address, maybe not.